# ECS Fargate Routing to 20+ Containers from ALB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, containers, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

I'm running 20 + Java ElasticBeanstalk Instances that are all using Classic Load Balancers and the works (autoscaling, security groups, etc). I'm trying to figure out how to improve this setup and move it to ECS and reduce overall resource consumption.

The question I'm looking to figure out is if it's possible to have Fargate handle 20+ different host and path match conditions to 20+ different containers in a single service.

I have a POC in place where I have my containers spinning up on an ECS EC2 instance, instead of Fargate but I can see everything is working when I visit my Route53 CNAME I'm testing with.

I have traffic coming into a main ALB that's rerouting http traffic -> https. After https, the traffic is filtered through rules that route traffic based on a host and path condition.

```
First rule
host is hello.world.com + path is /java Then forward to helloworld-target-group

Second rule
host is new.world.com + path is /java Then forward to welcomeworld-target-group

and so on
```

I'm reading that a single ECS service can only have 1 ALB with a max of 5 target groups and my initial thinking was to have the 20+ target groups on a single service with an ALB and 20+ containers.

Now I'm thinking as a possible side solution, I could have 5 different services making use of the 5 target group per service limit.

The containers will all have the same docker image. The only difference will be the environmental variables on the containers. (I need the containers to each have different environmental variables so that java will know which db to use.)

Has anyone looked at a similar problem or know of a better solution?

Edit: I might be wrong or AWS has updated the routing rules but as of now the answer I've landed on is not to use Fargate to route traffic to 20+ containers. Use an ECS EC2 instance to setup 20+ target groups that all route to separate ports on the EC2 Instance. This way you can route traffic to 20+ containers from a single instance which is pretty cool.